# Getting Blurred image from native camera in android

Tags: android

I am capturing the image from the native camera of device and showing it in another activity using imageview.Problem is that in OnActivityResult method i am getting the bitmap which is blurred.I want to get Bitmap of original size image.can anyone help me??Thanks in advance.This is my code in which i am getting the bitmap in onActivityResult method and save it to the sd card.The image is getting blurred from sd card.

```
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Intent mIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(mIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                WookAtMeStaticVariables.retakePic=false;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                clickmessage="OnClickevent Exception"+e.getMessage();
                showAlertDialogForCameraClickException(TakePic.this);

            }

        }
    });




        @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK)

        {

               imageBitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
               imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (imageBitmap,750,750, false);
               File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"WookAtMepic"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
               WookAtMeStaticVariables.mImageFilePath=file.getAbsolutePath();

               OutputStream outStream = null;
               try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                   }

                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


            Intent afterTakePicIntent= new Intent(TakePic.this,AfterTakePic.class);
            startActivity(afterTakePicIntent);

            }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        resultMessage="OnResultevent Exception"+e.getMessage();
        showAlertDialogForCameraResultException(TakePic.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which device are you using? Some cameras (such as in Samsung's Galaxy Tab II) won't focus. EVER.

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: Why don't you post your code? I'm not aware of focusing issues on the Galaxy S, so it's not the hardware.

Comment: This is my code in which i am getting the bitmap in onActivityResult method and save it to the sd card.The image is getting blurred from sd card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily overlooked, but the image you receive from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is going to be a small bitmap, UNLESS you specify [EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT). See notes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). The reason for that is that a full-scale image is likely going to be pretty large, in the order of several MB, and passing that amount of data around with as in intent-extra is problematic.

So you'll need to pass it the storage URI for a temporary file (or you can publish your own content-provider), and then resize it.